# Is cpu,gpu,ssd "sound/noise" dangerous if all performance are normal? (Detail in post)

Tags: ssd, noise

#### Problem:

My brand new PC, makes noise and this noise increases during heavy use. I am not sure if this sound is from SSD or CPU or GPU or fans. But with the tests I took, GPU and fans even in stress level test doesn't make sound like the ones I hear. So my doubt is SSD and CPU.

I hear 2 different sound!

1. One sound is continuously playing and is VERY similar to the sound in this video (SSH sound: [youtube.com/watch?v=KS-BHI667po](http://youtube.com/watch?v=KS-BHI667po)). So my main guess is that it come from SSD. (Samsung 970 EVO Plus)
2. On the other hand, when I put my ear close to the place where the CPU is connected (my ear is on behind side of motherboard), I hear very low and small sounds like a tick or morse code (while the CPU should be silent, right?). Intel 13th generation CPU.

---

#### The main question:

I don't have the possibility to do more detailed tests of each piece at the moment and I know SSD its not suppose to make noise but they are, Google is full of them. So my real question that I want to know is this:

If the performance/temperature of the computer, whether in the heavy game, in AI or in all cases, is fast and without any problems, and the only thing is this sounds, can I ignore them? (Even the CPU tiny tickz?) Regardless of which piece it is (CPU or GPU or SSD)? Or are these sounds a sign of a problem for sure?

Comment: Can you return it?

Comment: Just return the PC. Tell them you are concerned about noise.

Comment: It’s impossible for a SSD to make a sound. There are no moving parts. It’s not coil whine….

Answer (score 0):

SSDs have no moving parts, so they can't make a noise.  I dont hear a high pitch sound.  What I hear is just bursts of noise that are probably getting injected into your audio output.

This could happen,

- if the audio cable is not shielded,
- or the connector is loose
- or the sound card is not of a good quality
- or you are using headphones with noise cancelling on (some cheap ones make this sort of noise)